# Is it possible to run test in rails without db:create and db:migrate?

Tags: testing, ruby-on-rails-5

i just want to know and want to try, is it possible run rails test without db:create and db:migrate?

I'm new with ruby on rails (rails 5.2.3). i've tried and it cant run the test, i think fixture already handle the data for dummy. Or maybe i missed some steps?

Comment: ActiveRecord introspects the database to figure out each model's attributes and their types. You might be able to get it working just from `db/schema.rb`, but you wouldn't be able to do any queries.

Comment: you're right,  
`ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError: FATAL:  database "db_test" does not exist` , hmm okay, can you give me some sample with `db/schema.rb` , is it still use db:create/migrate? @Schwern

Answer (score 0):

You still have to create the db test before you can run any test. Try this in terminal:

```
RAILS_ENV=test bin/rails db:create
RAILS_ENV=test bin/rails db:migrate
```

then try again with your tests. Hope this helps